# MySQL crash while generating entity data model in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

When I try to generate the entity models from the existing database the mysqld service crashes.
This does not occur with MySQL 8.0.20, only with 8.0.21. I was hoping to use the new json features added to the update but this problem is driving me nuts.

[MySQL Installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwfSn.jpg)

The entity wizard connects ok with the server and show the tables I want to import, when the importing process begin throws an exception "connection lost" and I see the mysqld.exe stopped.

The MySQL log show nothing useful except for part of the query generated by the wizard:

```
15:45:58 UTC - mysqld got exception 0xc0000005 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x1c9945fcfc0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
7ff7c812f74b    mysqld.exe!?get_full_info@Item_aggregate_type@@IEAAXPEAVItem@@@Z()
7ff7c81228d6    mysqld.exe!??0Item_aggregate_type@@QEAA@PEAVTHD@@PEAVItem@@@Z()
7ff7c83ab288    mysqld.exe!?prepare@SELECT_LEX_UNIT@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAVQuery_result@@_K2@Z()
7ff7c841dd0e    mysqld.exe!?resolve_derived@TABLE_LIST@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff7c83d40d6    mysqld.exe!?resolve_placeholder_tables@SELECT_LEX@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff7c83d25aa    mysqld.exe!?prepare@SELECT_LEX@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7c83ab191    mysqld.exe!?prepare@SELECT_LEX_UNIT@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAVQuery_result@@_K2@Z()
7ff7c841dd0e    mysqld.exe!?resolve_derived@TABLE_LIST@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff7c83d40d6    mysqld.exe!?resolve_placeholder_tables@SELECT_LEX@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff7c83d25aa    mysqld.exe!?prepare@SELECT_LEX@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7c83ab191    mysqld.exe!?prepare@SELECT_LEX_UNIT@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAVQuery_result@@_K2@Z()
7ff7c841dd0e    mysqld.exe!?resolve_derived@TABLE_LIST@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff7c83d40d6    mysqld.exe!?resolve_placeholder_tables@SELECT_LEX@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff7c83d25aa    mysqld.exe!?prepare@SELECT_LEX@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7c832980c    mysqld.exe!?prepare_inner@Sql_cmd_select@@MEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7c832942c    mysqld.exe!?prepare@Sql_cmd_dml@@UEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7c8325ef5    mysqld.exe!?execute@Sql_cmd_dml@@UEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7c822d36d    mysqld.exe!?mysql_execute_command@@YAHPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff7c822dfc9    mysqld.exe!?mysql_parse@@YAXPEAVTHD@@PEAVParser_state@@@Z()
7ff7c8226eb2    mysqld.exe!?dispatch_command@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@PEBTCOM_DATA@@W4enum_server_command@@@Z()
7ff7c8227e6e    mysqld.exe!?do_command@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7c80726c8    mysqld.exe!?modify_thread_cache_size@Per_thread_connection_handler@@SAXK@Z()
7ff7c93322a1    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7c8f3739c    mysqld.exe!?my_thread_join@@YAHPEAUmy_thread_handle@@PEAPEAX@Z()
7fff75851542    ucrtbase.dll!_configthreadlocale()
7fff77ab6fd4    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
7fff77bfcec1    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (1c999a99d08): SELECT
`Project7`.`C12` AS `C1`, 
`Project7`.`C1` AS `C2`, 
`Project7`.`C2` AS `C3`, 
`Project7`.`C3` AS `C4`, 
`Project7`.`C4` AS `C5`, 
`Project7`.`C5` AS `C6`, 
`Project7`.`C6` AS `C7`, 
`Project7`.`C7` AS `C8`, 
`Project7`.`C8` AS `C9`, 
`Project7`.`C9` AS `C10`, 
`Project7`.`C10` AS `C11`
FROM (SELECT
`UnionAll3`.`SchemaName` AS `C1`, 
`UnionAll3`.`Name` AS `C2`, 
`UnionAll3`.`ReturnTypeName` AS `C3`, 
`UnionAll3`.`IsAggregate` AS `C4`, 
`UnionAll3`.`C1` AS `C5`, 
`UnionAll3`.`IsBuiltIn` AS `C6`, 
`UnionAll3`.`IsNiladic` AS `C7`, 
`UnionAll3`.`C2` AS `C8`, 
`UnionAll3`.`C3` AS `C9`, 
`UnionAll3`.`C4` AS `C10`, 
`UnionAll3`.`C5` AS `C11`, 
1 AS `C12`
FROM ((SELECT
`Extent1`.`SchemaName`, 
`Extent1`.`Name`, 
`Extent1`.`ReturnTypeName`, 
`Extent1`.`IsAggregate`, 
1 AS `C1`, 
`Extent1`.`IsBuiltIn`, 
`Extent1`.`IsNiladic`, 
`UnionAll1`.`Name` AS `C2`, 
`UnionAll1`.`TypeName` AS `C3`, 
`UnionAll1`.`Mode` AS `C4`, 
`UnionAll1`.`Ordinal` AS `C5`
FROM (
        SELECT /* Funct
Connection ID (thread ID): 18
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Is this a bug or some kind of configuration error on my part?

Comment: If this is a crash in mysqld.exe that's new in 8.0.21 (and not in 8.0.20), it may be best to report it to the MySQL bug tracker: https://bugs.mysql.com/report.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proved to be a bug in the new query optimizations, but I was able to find a workaround by disabling some of the optimizations on the server.

Here is the command I used:

```
Set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off,subquery_to_derived=off,prefer_ordering_index=off,semijoin=off';
```

Hope it helps until they fix the bug.