# Mysql Server stopped when add ADO.net [ASP.net API]

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I installed MySql.Data.EntityFramework from NUGET version 8.0.21 and Mysql for Visual Studio from mysql installer version 1.2.9
when I add Ado.net item and select All table and click "Finish". I got error from Visual Studio and MySql Service stopped.

And I see mysql server error log from this below

```
02:06:09 UTC - mysqld got exception 0xc0000005 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x24ee3d778b0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
7ff7378af74b    mysqld.exe!?get_full_info@Item_aggregate_type@@IEAAXPEAVItem@@@Z()
7ff7378a28d6    mysqld.exe!??0Item_aggregate_type@@QEAA@PEAVTHD@@PEAVItem@@@Z()
7ff737b2b288    mysqld.exe!?prepare@SELECT_LEX_UNIT@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAVQuery_result@@_K2@Z()
7ff737b9dd0e    mysqld.exe!?resolve_derived@TABLE_LIST@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff737b540d6    mysqld.exe!?resolve_placeholder_tables@SELECT_LEX@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff737b525aa    mysqld.exe!?prepare@SELECT_LEX@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff737b2b191    mysqld.exe!?prepare@SELECT_LEX_UNIT@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAVQuery_result@@_K2@Z()
7ff737b9dd0e    mysqld.exe!?resolve_derived@TABLE_LIST@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff737b540d6    mysqld.exe!?resolve_placeholder_tables@SELECT_LEX@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff737b525aa    mysqld.exe!?prepare@SELECT_LEX@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff737b2b191    mysqld.exe!?prepare@SELECT_LEX_UNIT@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAVQuery_result@@_K2@Z()
7ff737b9dd0e    mysqld.exe!?resolve_derived@TABLE_LIST@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff737b540d6    mysqld.exe!?resolve_placeholder_tables@SELECT_LEX@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff737b525aa    mysqld.exe!?prepare@SELECT_LEX@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff737aa980c    mysqld.exe!?prepare_inner@Sql_cmd_select@@MEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff737aa942c    mysqld.exe!?prepare@Sql_cmd_dml@@UEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff737aa5ef5    mysqld.exe!?execute@Sql_cmd_dml@@UEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7379ad36d    mysqld.exe!?mysql_execute_command@@YAHPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff7379adfc9    mysqld.exe!?mysql_parse@@YAXPEAVTHD@@PEAVParser_state@@@Z()
7ff7379a6eb2    mysqld.exe!?dispatch_command@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@PEBTCOM_DATA@@W4enum_server_command@@@Z()
7ff7379a7e6e    mysqld.exe!?do_command@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7377f26c8    mysqld.exe!?modify_thread_cache_size@Per_thread_connection_handler@@SAXK@Z()
7ff738ab22a1    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7386b739c    mysqld.exe!?my_thread_join@@YAHPEAUmy_thread_handle@@PEAPEAX@Z()
7ff928840e82    ucrtbase.dll!_beginthreadex()
7ff9294f7bd4    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
7ff92ac4ce51    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
```

More error

```
Query (24ee9996b48): SELECT
`Project7`.`C12` AS `C1`, 
`Project7`.`C1` AS `C2`, 
`Project7`.`C2` AS `C3`, 
`Project7`.`C3` AS `C4`, 
`Project7`.`C4` AS `C5`, 
`Project7`.`C5` AS `C6`, 
`Project7`.`C6` AS `C7`, 
`Project7`.`C7` AS `C8`, 
`Project7`.`C8` AS `C9`, 
`Project7`.`C9` AS `C10`, 
`Project7`.`C10` AS `C11`
FROM (SELECT
`UnionAll3`.`SchemaName` AS `C1`, 
`UnionAll3`.`Name` AS `C2`, 
`UnionAll3`.`ReturnTypeName` AS `C3`, 
`UnionAll3`.`IsAggregate` AS `C4`, 
`UnionAll3`.`C1` AS `C5`, 
`UnionAll3`.`IsBuiltIn` AS `C6`, 
`UnionAll3`.`IsNiladic` AS `C7`, 
`UnionAll3`.`C2` AS `C8`, 
`UnionAll3`.`C3` AS `C9`, 
`UnionAll3`.`C4` AS `C10`, 
`UnionAll3`.`C5` AS `C11`, 
1 AS `C12`
FROM ((SELECT
`Extent1`.`SchemaName`, 
`Extent1`.`Name`, 
`Extent1`.`ReturnTypeName`, 
`Extent1`.`IsAggregate`, 
1 AS `C1`, 
`Extent1`.`IsBuiltIn`, 
`Extent1`.`IsNiladic`, 
`UnionAll1`.`Name` AS `C2`, 
`UnionAll1`.`TypeName` AS `C3`, 
`UnionAll1`.`Mode` AS `C4`, 
`UnionAll1`.`Ordinal` AS `C5`
FROM (
        SELECT /* Funct
Connection ID (thread ID): 9
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2020-08-30T02:55:49.311125Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2020-08-30T02:55:49.315493Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.21) starting as process 14424
2020-08-30T02:55:49.374995Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-08-30T02:55:50.510722Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-08-30T02:55:50.835220Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-08-30T02:55:50.867641Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2020-08-30T02:55:50.880215Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2020-08-30T02:55:50.950247Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-08-30T02:55:50.952201Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2020-08-30T02:55:51.023655Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.21'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-08-30T03:01:46.834239Z 0 [System] [MY-013105] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown.
2020-08-30T03:01:48.837209Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Forcing close of thread 8  user: 'root'.
2020-08-30T03:01:48.838932Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Forcing close of thread 9  user: 'root'.
2020-08-30T03:01:49.403927Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Comment: This is a proper crash, we cannot really do anything about it. Submit this as a bug report on mysql.com.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/63362585/23633.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger: Did you flag the duplicate?

Comment: I tried to flag this question as a duplicate, but couldn't (because the other question doesn't have an answer yet). The answer is: file a bug with Oracle.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger: NP, I found an issue with an accepted answer :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL crash on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071309/mysql-crash-on-startup)